# The view 'Index' or its master was not found , is this because invalid user credentials

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, connection-string

I found many questions same to my question but non of them solved my problem

Ill explain this briefly,I have created MVC 5 web app. In that application
 Once I debug my applications its directing to `~/Account/Login` page

then once I insert valid username password it can direct to `~/Home/Index` page

this application previously worked well, but then I changed it to Local DB

this how connection strings defined for server DB previously

```
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.158.1.205;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.158.1.205;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=**;Password=****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.albaraka_model.csdl|res://*/Models.albaraka_model.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBName_model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.158.1.205;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

this is how connection strings configured for local DB Now

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBName_model.csdl|res://*/Models.DBName_model.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBName_model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=ALBARAKA;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Is this because invalid connection string define ? or is this because invalid username password(currently its not handled on client side or server side)

this is my post method of login method

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }


            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");

                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });

                case SignInStatus.Failure:

                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");

                    return View("Index", "Home", model);
            }
        }
```

Really appreciate your help

Comment: No it's because it looking for the `View` and it can't locate it

Comment: @jamiedanq but I can see its located in correct folder :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
return View("Index", "Home", model);
```

to the Views fullpath and the model

```
return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml", model); //note this is an example so replace the path with yours
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home", model);
```

Refer to this link if you need further clarifications https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: whats happens to model return

Comment: you can add that as well